# How to access and retrieve real-time data from Avaya database?

Tags: avaya

I seek to retrieve Agents and Jobs real-time information and send it via web.

My company is using Avaya Proactive Contact 5.1 standalone. The objective is a way to do this without purchasing any extra service or component from Avaya.. i.e. free.

I read something about Clint or RT_Socket but it wasn't very clear or precise. Could you help me a bit with this??

BIG THANKS in advance.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get a free account on http://www.devconnectprogram.com/ and search through the SDK and API docs to see if you can get what you need.

There are so many API's and SDK's on the POM solution...
[image: Avaya POM Dev]

good luck!